# url rewrite not working on server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this site is flooded with similar questions but nothing worked for me. My current .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This is working on localhost, when I go to `localhost/mysite/register/` I'm server the correct file,which is:  `localhost/mysite/register.php`, but on the server when I go to `dev.mysite.com/register/` I get `404` error, I know this has some thing to do with the different files structure between localhost and the server, Also tried this for the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^register/?$ /register.php [L,NC]
```

And yes rewrite module is in fact loaded,

Comment: This is possibly a vhost issue, do you have a host setup for the domain name you use externally?

Comment: Could you explain please

Comment: Look for an entry in your config that contains the VirtualHost directive. You'll likely need to add another entry identical to the current entry that has ServerName set to whatever domain name you are trying to connect via.

Comment: @Prix I will, as soon as I get a chance to test it, currently we're having some issues with our server.